# jQuery hover effect on current element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have a list of Divs which contain an image. When I hover over a div, I want the image to move up (I'm doing this by altering the image css on hover). The issue I'm having is that when I hover over one div, all the images in all divs are changing. Instead, I want the hover effect just to take place on the div I'm hovering over. Here is my current jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  screenshotHeight = $('.l_admin-product-screenshot img').height(); 

  $('.l_admin-product').hover(function () {
    $('.l_admin-product-screenshot img').css({
      top: -screenshotHeight
    });
  },

                              function () {
    $('.l_admin-product-screenshot img').css({
      top: '0'
    });
  });

});
```

Here is my html structure:

```
<div class="l_admin-products">

<div class="l_admin-product" tabindex="0">
            <input name="layes-preset-layout" id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-1-radio" class="l_admin-hide" type="radio" value="skizzar-homepage-2">
            <label for="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-1-radio">
                <input id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-1-title" type="hidden" value="Splash Page">
                <input id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-1-widget_data" type="hidden" value="">
                <div class="l_admin-product-screenshot">
                    <img src="http://demo.skizzar.com/wp-content/themes/pastorious/assets/preset-images/new_homepage21_w515.png" width="320" style="top: 0px;">                 </div>
                <h3 class="l_admin-product-name" id="skizzar-homepage-2">Splash Page</h3>
                <div class="l_admin-product-actions">
                    <a class="button button-primary customize load-customize" id="layers-generate-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-1" data-key="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-1">
                        Select                      </a>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>

<div class="l_admin-product" tabindex="0">
            <input name="layes-preset-layout" id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-2-radio" class="l_admin-hide" type="radio" value="skizzar-homepage-2">
            <label for="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-2-radio">
                <input id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-2-title" type="hidden" value="Splash Page">
                <input id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-2-widget_data" type="hidden" value="">
                <div class="l_admin-product-screenshot">
                    <img src="http://demo.skizzar.com/wp-content/themes/pastorious/assets/preset-images/new_homepage2_w515.png" width="320" style="top: 0px;">                  </div>
                <h3 class="l_admin-product-name" id="skizzar-homepage-2">Splash Page</h3>
                <div class="l_admin-product-actions">
                    <a class="button button-primary customize load-customize" id="layers-generate-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-2" data-key="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-2">
                        Select                      </a>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>

<div class="l_admin-product" tabindex="0">
            <input name="layes-preset-layout" id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-3-radio" class="l_admin-hide" type="radio" value="skizzar-homepage-3">
            <label for="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-3-radio">
                <input id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-3-title" type="hidden" value="Splash Page">
                <input id="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-3-widget_data" type="hidden" value="">
                <div class="l_admin-product-screenshot">
                    <img src="http://demo.skizzar.com/wp-content/themes/pastorious/assets/preset-images/new_homepage3_w515.png" width="320" style="top: 0px;">                  </div>
                <h3 class="l_admin-product-name" id="skizzar-homepage-2">Splash Page</h3>
                <div class="l_admin-product-actions">
                    <a class="button button-primary customize load-customize" id="layers-generate-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-3" data-key="layers-preset-layout-skizzar-homepage-3">
                        Select                      </a>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: show your html also

Comment: please add html to the example.

Comment: @L.Vadim added HTML - just tidying it up now

Comment: Please us the script runner

Comment: I feel like `$('.l_admin-product-screenshot img')` is getting ALL of your images. I might be wrong though. Might be easily resolved by using `this` if it is the issue.

Comment: @A.Lau I believe you're right - I'm not very well versed on how to use 'this' though - let me have a quick research and see what I can come up with

Comment: An easy way to find out is to `console.log($('.l_admin-product-screenshot img'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.l_admin-product').hover(function () {
  $this = $(this);

  $this.find('.l_admin-product-screenshot > img').css({
    top: -screenshotHeight
  });
},function () {
  $this.find('.l_admin-product-screenshot img').css({
  top: '0'
  });
});
```

Try with `$this` to point current image.

Comment: Yes this works, although how do I find the height of $this image that is being hovered over (for the value of screenshotHeight)

Comment: @SamSlirrow  -  screenshotHeight = $this.find('.l_admin-product-screenshot >  img').height();